# Removing integers from a list of list of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a list of list of lists of strings for which I would like to remove the integers

```
[[[u'HH', u'AH0', u'L', u'OW1'], [u'HH', u'EH0', u'L', u'OW1']]]
```

The above lists should return

```
[[[u'HH', u'AH', u'L', u'OW'], [u'HH', u'EH', u'L', u'OW']]]
```

I have tried to use a filter

```
filter(lambda i: not str.isdigit(i), phoneseqList[0])
```

but this does not appear to work

Comment: Can you provide the real code you used? The `filter` by itself won't tell us if you're failing to use it correctly in other ways; there are obvious issues already (`phoneseqList[0]` is presumably wrong, since a single level of indexing is still working with `list` of `list` of `unicode`). Also, to be clear, is this Python 2 or Python 3 code? The `u` prefix on the strings makes Py2 likely, but it's legal in both Py2 and Py3.

Answer (score 5):

For an arbitrarily nested list of strings, here is a recursive solution that will remove any digits from all of the strings

```
def remove_digits(i):
    if isinstance(i, list):
        return [remove_digits(j) for j in i]
    else:
        return ''.join(j for j in i if not j.isdigit())
```

Example

```
>>> l = [[[u'HH', u'AH0', u'L', u'OW1'], [u'HH', u'EH0', u'L', u'OW1']]]
>>> remove_digits(l)
[[['HH', 'AH', 'L', 'OW'], ['HH', 'EH', 'L', 'OW']]]
```

**Edit**
To add an extension to each string you could do the same idea

```
def add_ext(i, ext):
    if isinstance(i, list):
        return [add_ext(j, ext) for j in i]
    else:
        return i + ext
```

So you could say

```
>>> add_ext(l, '.jpeg')
```

Comment: Does this same logic work when it comes to appending things to the list ? I now want to add a ".jpeg" string to each element but I am unsure what the join method is doing in the else

Comment: @NeptuneGamer Yes the same idea applies, see my edit.

Comment: Also you could do it all at once if you want, so the `else` case could be `''.join(blah) + ext`

Comment: why not `return re.sub("\d+","",i)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.translate` to remove the digits:

```
l = [[[u'HH2', u'AH0', u'L', u'OW1'], [u'HH', u'EH0', u'L', u'OW1']]]

tbl = {ord(d): u"" for d in u"0123456789"}
for sub in l:
    sub[:] = [[s.translate(tbl) for s in w] for w in sub]
```

Output:

```
[[[u'HH', u'AH', u'L', u'OW'], [u'HH', u'EH', u'L', u'OW']]]
```

If you want it for arbitrary nesting:

```
l = [[[u'HH2', u'AH0', u'L', u'OW1'], [u'HH', u'EH0', u'L', u'OW1']]]

def rem_d(l, tbl):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        return [rem_d(ele, tbl) for ele in l]
    return l.translate(tbl)



tbl = {ord(d): u"" for d in u"0123456789"}


print(list(rem_d(l, tbl)))
```

output:

```
[[[u'HH', u'AH', u'L', u'OW'], [u'HH', u'EH', u'L', u'OW']]]
```

translate will be a lot faster than iterating over every digit:

```
In [13]: l = [[[u'HH2', u'AH0', u'L', u'OW1'], [u'HH', u'EH0', u'L', u'OW1']]]

In [14]: l = [l[0] for _ in range(100000)]

In [15]: timeit rem_d(l, tbl)
1 loops, best of 3: 777 ms per loop

In [16]: timeit remove_digits(l)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.83 s per loop
In [17]: remove_digits(l) == rem_d(l,tbl)
Out[17]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the digits are at the end of your words and each item you want is at most 2 characters, you could slice the string to just extract the first two characters. This would leave out the digit on the end.

```
l = [[u'HH', u'AH0', u'L', u'OW1'], [u'HH', u'EH0', u'L', u'OW1']]

newL = []
for sublist in l:
    tempL = []
    for item in sublist:
        tempL.append(item[:2])
    newL.append(tempL)
print newL
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @CoryKramer regarding a recursive implementation (unless the case is always a list of a list of lists). The following implementation is similar, it only reserve the unicode encoding if it is necessary.

```
import re

lst = [[[u'HH', u'AH0', u'L', u'OW1'], [u'HH', u'EH0', u'L', u'OW1']]]

def removeDigits(lst):
    for i,l in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(l, list):
            removeDigits(l)
        else:
            lst[i] = re.sub('[0-9]+','', l)

removeDigits(lst)
print lst
```

#### output

```
[[[u'HH', u'AH', u'L', u'OW'], [u'HH', u'EH', u'L', u'OW']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are always at the end, you can use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip):

```
>>> phone_seq_list = [['HH', 'AH0', 'L', 'OW1'], ['HH', 'EH0', 'L', 'OW1']]
>>> [[s.rstrip('0123456789') for s in l] for l in phone_seq_list]
[['HH', 'AH', 'L', 'OW'], ['HH', 'EH', 'L', 'OW']]
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that digit characters will only occur at the tail of each string, which happens to be the case for the given example but isn't specified in the question (which only mentions removing the integers).

Comment: You're right, I just modified my answer to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently looking at each string in the first nested `list`, which is itself a `list` and therefore lacks the `isdigit()` method. You need to process each character.

```
phoneseqList = [[[u'HH', u'AH0', u'L', u'OW1'], [u'HH', u'EH0', u'L', u'OW1']]]
newlist = [[[''.join(element for element in item if not element.isdigit()) for item in sublist] for sublist in phoneseqList[0]]]
```

Result:

```
>>> newlist
[[[u'HH', u'AH', u'L', u'OW'], [u'HH', u'EH', u'L', u'OW']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just nest loops further:

```
from itertools import filterfalse  # ifilterfalse on Python 2

for sublist1 in toplist:
    for sublist2 in sublist1:
        for i, s in enumerate(sublist2):
           sublist2[i] = ''.join(let for let in s if not let.isdigit())
```

Yes, you could use the most terrible of all nested list comprehensions to create a new `list` of `list` of `list`s and replace the existing one, but in this case, it's rather more straightforward/readable to mutate the existing `list` in place with explicit loops. You can always `copy.deepcopy` the original top level `list` if you need to unmodified version later.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
def strip_digits(text):
    return ''.join([c for c in text if not c.isdigit()])


def filter_list(outer):
    return [[strip_digits(i) for i in inner] for inner in outer]
```

With the accompanied unit test if you are into the TDD kind of way :)

```
class FilterListTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_filter_list(self):
        # Arrange
        actual = [[u'HH', u'AH0', u'L', u'OW1'], [u'HH', u'EH0', u'L', u'OW1']]
        expected = [[u'HH', u'AH', u'L', u'OW'], [u'HH', u'EH', u'L', u'OW']]

        # Act & Assert
        self.assertEquals(filter_list(actual), expected)
```